# class_weight in fit_generator as np.array or dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, dictionary, keras, binary-data

I am trying to recreate binary image using a `UNet`. But the classification labels are extremely skewed (~10% are 0s and rest are 1s in the image). So I got the `weights` for each class using `skearn`. This is what I do:

```
wts = np.array([5.76901408, 0.54744721])
class_wts = dict(enumerate(wts))
```

Now, when I put this in `fit_generator`:

```
history_sgd = model.fit_generator(training_generator, validation_data=valid_generator, steps_per_epoch=train_steps, validation_steps=valid_steps, epochs=epochs, verbose=1, class_weight = class_wts)
```

I get the following error:

> ValueError: `class_weight` not supported for 3+ dimensional targets.

Could this be because of the `generator` shape? Because that would be of the shape `(batch_size, <image_size>)`.

Moreover, when I use `class_weight` as `numpy array` instead of `dictionary`, the code works. Why does that happen? I checked a lot of resources online but I cannot figure the difference between the two and why the numpy array format works but not the dictionary.